# Kafka Integration in Apache Heron

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, heron

I am trying to integrate Kafka with a Heron Topology. However, I am not able to find any examples with the latest version of Heron (0.17.5). Is there any example that can be shared or any suggestions on how to implement a custom Kafka Spout and Kafka Bolt?

**Edit 1:**

I believe **KafkaSpout** and **KafkaBolt** were intentionally deprecated in Heron to give way for the new **Streamlet API**. I am currently to see if I can build a **KafkaSource** and **KafkaSink** using the Streamlet API. However, I am getting the below exception, when I try to create a **KafkaConsumer** within the **Source**.

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at com.twitter.heron.api.utils.Utils.serialize(Utils.java:97)
```

**Edit 2:**

Fixed the above issue. I was initializing the `KafkaConsumer` in the Constructor which was wrong. Initializing the same in the `setup()` method fixed it.

Comment: If Heron is roughly Storm compatible, what specific issues are you having?

Comment: The KafkaSpout provided by Storm is deprecated.

Comment: According to what? Does the documentation give an alternative?

Comment: Streamlet API seems to be the alternative for Spout and Bolt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get this done using Streamlet API for Heron. I'm posting the same here. Hope it helps others facing the same problem.

**Kafka Source**

```
public class KafkaSource implements Source {

    private String streamName;

    private Consumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer;
    private List<String> kafkaTopic;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("KafkaSource");

    @Override
    public void setup(Context context) {

        this.streamName = context.getStreamName();

        kafkaTopic = Arrays.asList(KafkaProperties.KAFKA_TOPIC);

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", KafkaProperties.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
        props.put("group.id", KafkaProperties.CONSUMER_GROUP_ID);
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", KafkaProperties.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT);
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", KafkaProperties.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS);
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", KafkaProperties.SESSION_TIMEOUT);
        props.put("key.deserializer", KafkaProperties.KEY_DESERIALIZER);
        props.put("value.deserializer", KafkaProperties.VALUE_DESERIALIZER);
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", KafkaProperties.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET);
        props.put("max.poll.records", KafkaProperties.MAX_POLL_RECORDS);
        props.put("max.poll.interval.ms", KafkaProperties.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS);

        this.kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

        kafkaConsumer.subscribe(kafkaTopic);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection get() {

        List<String> kafkaRecords = new ArrayList<>();

        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);

        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            String rVal = record.value();
            kafkaRecords.add(rVal);
        }

        return kafkaRecords;
    }

    @Override
    public void cleanup() {
        kafkaConsumer.wakeup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to integrate **KafkaSpout** to Heron using **the Java API**, not Streamlet API?